# Finding closest spellings by the same first letter via different distance measures

Tags: python, distance, n-gram, corpus

I am trying to write a function that will find closest spellings for a word (which may have been incorrectly spelled) 'by the same first letter' through different n-grams and distance measures.

For what I currently have

```css
from nltk.corpus import words
from nltk import ngrams
from nltk.metrics.distance import edit_distance, jaccard_distance
first_letters = ['A','B','C']
spellings = words.words()
    def recommendation(word):
        n = 3
# n means 'n'-grams, here I use 3 as an example 
        spellings_new = [w for w in spellings if (w[0] in first_letters)]
        dists = [________(set(ngrams(word, n)), set(ngrams(w, n))) for w in spellings_new]
# ______ is the distance measure
        return spellings_new[dists.index(min(dists))]
```

The rest seems straightforward, but I don't know how to specify 'same initial letter' condition. In particular, if the misspelled word starts with the letter 'A', then the corrected word recommended from '.words' having the minimum distance measure with the misspelled word should also starts with 'A'. So on and so forth.
As you can see from the above function block, I use '(w[0] in first_letters)' as my 'initial letter condition,' but this doesn't do the trick and always return letters that start with different initials. 
I have yet to find similar threads on this board addressing my question here, it will be appreciated if anyone could enlighten me on how to specify the 'initial letter condition'. If this question has somehow been asked before and deemed inappropriate, I will remove it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're really quite close. `w[0] == word[0]` can be used to check if the first letter is the same. After that `set(w)` and `set(word)` can be used to change the words into sets of letters. I then passed it into jaccard_distance, only because that's what you already had imported. It's possible there's a better solution.

```
def recommendation(word):
    n = 3
    # n means 'n'-grams, here I use 3 as an example
    spellings_new = [w for w in spellings if (w[0] == word[0])]
    dists = [jaccard_distance(set(w), set(word)) for w in spellings_new]
    return spellings_new[dists.index(min(dists))]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Do I change the condition to (w[0] == first_letters[0])?

Comment: Oh, ok, I got it. Thanks again!